# How to display value labels in a table

Tags: python, statistics, label

I am fairly new to Python and I am struggling to replicate something that is quite easy to do in a standard statistical package such as SAS and SPSS.

Basically, I am trying to calculate a frequency table on a variable, "type", which is categorical but stored as an integer ranging from 1 to 5. Each of these values correspond to a distinct category e.g. 1 is Professional;2 is Manager etc. I am using the panda crosstab command.
When doing a cross-tab to get the number of people in my dataframe belonging to each category, I want the column (or row) headings to display the label e.g. "Professional" instead of the actual value e.g. "1" to aid interpretation.

I have tried creating a dictionary to assign each key (e.g. my values 1-5) to each value (i.e. my labels), but I can't find out how to modify the cross-tab command to pick the dictionary labels.
I am sure there must be an easy way of doing this!
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to change the column headers:

```
import pandas as pd

# Dictionary mapping category numbers to titles
category_map = {1: "Professional", 2: "Manager", 3: "Etc."}

# Dummy dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    1: ["Hello", "mister", "professional"],
    2: ["Hello", "mister", "manager"],
    3: ["Who", "are", "you?"]
})

# Dataframe before conversion
print df

# Replace category numbers with titles
new_columns = [category_map[category_number] for category_number in list(df.columns)]
df.columns = new_columns

# Dataframe after conversion
print df
```

Which outputs:

```
              1        2     3
0         Hello    Hello   Who
1        mister   mister   are
2  professional  manager  you?
```

and:

```
   Professional  Manager  Etc.
0         Hello    Hello   Who
1        mister   mister   are
2  professional  manager  you?
```